# How to convert existing Angular 2 project to Meteor project

Tags: node.js, angular, meteor

I have finished creating an angular 2/ node.js project and I want to use Meteor so that I can create a mobile version. Can I simply create a new meteor project, copy and past all of my angular 2 code to the meteor project and be good to go? I have no idea what to do, I've searched everywhere.

Structure of my MEAN stack app:

```
server/
    node_modules/
    models/
    config/
    server.js
client/
    angular-src/
        node_modules/
        src/
            app/
                  ...
        tsconfig.json
        tslint.json
        package.json
        karma.conf.js
```

Do I have to completely start over to make a meteor app?

Thanks

Comment: why use Meteor for mobile app in the first place ?! since you build your project with angular2 and it's finished you can simply work with ionic2 to deliver the mobile app and apk. Or work on making it responsive and an progressive app. I see meteor just as an full stack framework I don't see it like an mobile framework.

Comment: Maybe you should try the tutorial on the Meteor website?

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix so if I used Ionic 2, then I would not have to change any of the angular 2 source code? I haven't looked at ionic 2 yet, I'll do that now.

Comment: @TaylorAckley I did. I followed along with it but I guess Meteor didn't accomplish the task I hoped it would

Comment: well most of your code would work you would only need to make changes to Markup and probably small rewrites. Still you have to build an Mobile app and things like navigation, ionic , offline states which you will have to work on, but since you have a finished project a lot of work is already done and you just have to migrate to ionic2 which uses angular2 and it seems you are familiar with it so the learning curve is not going to be a nightmare.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix Thank you!